# why does "select into" in a loop result in error "already an object named"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can this error be solved? The code produces an error when `@count` reaches 1:

> There is already an object named 'did2' in the database.

I read that I am not allowed to use `select into` twice in a loop (for whatever reason, in PL/SQL this is a very standard pattern).

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
WHILE (@count < 200)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @did2 DATETIME
    SELECT DATEADD(ss, @count, '01.01.2002 00:00:00') as did2 into did2 -- throws an error the 2nd time
    INSERT INTO [DbPriceHistorTesty].[dbo].[QuoteHistories]
               ([Id]
               ,[ContractId]
               ,[Open]
               ,[Close]
               ,[Min]
               ,[Max]
               ,[SenderId]
               ,[CreatedAt])
         VALUES (
               @did2
               ,1
               ,1
               ,1
               ,1
               ,1
               ,'1'
               ,GETDATE())
   SET @count = (@count + 1)
END
END
```

Comment: Are you normally an Oracle developer, by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a table `did2` for every rep.

You probably want this instead.

```
SELECT @did2 = DATEADD(ss, @count, '01.01.2002 00:00:00')
```

You should also consider changing your dateformat to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.

That way you will not be dependent on local datetime settings.

Comment: This won't fix the issue.  A `SELECT INTO` creates a new object and you can not have an existing object, which is why it doesn't work on the second iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below, it will solve your problem :

```
SET @did2 = DATEADD(ss, @count, '01.01.2002 00:00:00')
```

and declare variable out side the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, select into creates and inserts into a table.. the second time the table already exists..

I would suggest using CREATE TABLE outside of the loop and then INSERT within the loop (if that's what you're trying to do)

The other replies are probably better than mine because they have picked up on the fact you're not actually trying to insert into a table, rather a variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `SELECT INTO` creates a new table with the same schema as the object in the `FROM` clause.  This error will occur if there is already an object with the name in the database (in this case, 'did2').

You will need to create the receiving table outside of the loop for this to be successful.